# Flask and ndb.toplevel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, app-engine-ndb

When using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/), what is a sensible way to reap all async requests, much the way attaching [@ndb.toplevel](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async) to an outside function would be?

My first thought is to create an app with `app = Flask()`, then wrap that with e.g. `app = ndb.toplevel(app)`.

However, it occurred to me that there may be a more elegant or sensible solution to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think so. That sounds like the right thing to do.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum: I get a `RuntimeError: A tasklet should not yield plain values.` when I try the `app = ndb.toplevel(app)`; I do not have the time at the moment to investigate the cause, but it is an apparent problem with what should be the right solution. I will file an issue if I return to this, but thought to draw it to your attention in case you were interested.

Comment: That error means you have a place in your code that uses yield inappropriately.  All yields in tasklets should yield Futures.  The next version (in SDK 1.7.2) should give you a clearer error in this case, showing the name of the function and the specific value yielded.  Hopefully that will help you debug it.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum: You may be interested to know that the culprit was Google appstats i.e. if `from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording; app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)` appears before `app=toplevel(app)` for a flask application, GAE dev server will balk about yielding a plain value. The trivial solution seems to be reversing the order so `app=toplevel(app)` appears before appstats.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I have to think more about why that happens, but I suspect it is because appstats_wsgi_wrapper() uses yield to return multiple return values from the app it wraps.